# Golang：module declares its path as: bou.ke/monkey, but was required as: github.com/bouk/monkey

Tags: go, monkey

[image]

I want to have a mock test, so I import the `github.com/bouk/monkey`, it still can't work and give the following message.

I couldn't find the answer anywhere, could somebody help?

```
PS D:\xxx\awesomeGo> go get -u github.com/bouk/monkey         
go get: github.com/bouk/monkey@v1.0.2: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: bou.ke/monkey    
                but was required as: github.com/bouk/monkey
```

this is the target repo:

[image]

Comment: @Zombo I try it, but don't know what it means. Did the `github.com/bouk/monkey`  out of use?

Comment: @Wu-Yikun `github.com/bouk/monkey` isn't the name of the module. `bou.ke/monkey` is.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Haswin I use `bou.ke/monkey`, then it works.